# use map and itertools to add data from 2 different lists - multiprocessing

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, nested-lists, python-itertools

I have 3 list of lists.  The format looks like:

```
listA = [['324','1','Bob Smith','Manager','D3','T5'],['323','1','Jim Fourde','Manager','D2','T4'],['322','2','Jane Hamilton','Student','120','F5'],['314','1','Harry Rice','Manager','300','T1']]

listB = [['113','1','Jane Doe','Manager','D0','T4'],['120','1','Jane Crabtree','Manager','Y4','T4'],['122','2','Danny Copeland','Student','R4','F5'],['114','1','Jenny Hireh','Manager','G0','T1']]

listC = [['213','1','George Frank','Manager','T5','T4'],['120','1','Dana Fish','Manager','T4','T4'],['122','2','Johnny Truck','Student','G5','F5'],['114','1','Jordan Stuff','Manager','G6','T1']]
```

I am trying to add every combination of the values from element[0] across all 3 lists.  So logically as I iterate through the possibilities it should look like:

```
listA[0][0] + listB[0][0] + listC[0][0] 
listA[0][0] + listB[0][0] + listC[1][0]
listA[0][0] + listB[0][0] + listC[2][0]

becoming:

324+113+213 = 650
324+113+120 = 557
324+113+122 = 559
and so on...
```

Originally I accomplished this through nested for-loops, enumerating through each list.  In reality, the data is too large and I need to re-design to take advantage of multiprocessing.  My desired output would be:

```
Bob Smith, Jane Doe, George Frank = 650
Bob Smith, Jane Doe, Dana Fish = 557
Bob Smith, Jane Doe, Johnny Truck = 559
etc...
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
import csv
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product

**import CSV**
(import listA, listB, ListC)

def calculate(vals):
     sol = # How to add the element[0]?
     names = # How to track the names?
     print sol
     print names

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.map_async(calculate, product(*listA[0],listB[0],listC[0]))
```

My understanding of product() and what exactly I am passing to calculate() stops me dead in my tracks when I try to sum the element[0] while tracking the name (element[2]).  Any idea if I am on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.product` is indeed the way to go here. Using `itertools.product(listA, listB, listC)`, you get all possible combinations taking one from each list. Then, you just need to sum up the right elements:

```py
def calculate(vals):
    # `vals` is one of the items in `itertools.product`
    # Thus, it looks like [item from listA, item from listB, item from listC]
    sol = sum(int(x[0]) for x in vals) # Sum up the first sub-item (the number) of each item
    names = [x[2] for x in vals] # The second sub-item of each item contains the names
    # Output the values as described (or do whatever else you want with them)
    print(", ".join(names) + " = " + str(sol))
# ...
prod = itertools.product(listA, listB, listC)
result = pool.map_async(calculate, prod)
```

Comment: my list of lists can contain a lot of additional data, wont this result in a ton of overhead?  I was hoping there was a way to target just the elements i need (hence my failed attempt at passing product(lista[0], listb[0], listc[0])

Comment: `itertools.product` returns an [*iterator*](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0234/), meaning that the value is only calculated *when you request it*, and not in advance, so there should not be too much overhead.

Comment: You do get additional IPC overhead by passing all the elements in each sublist to the child, instead of just the data that is actually being operated on

Comment: OP (seems to) want[s] to go through all combinations. So the only information we can strip is the additional stuff in each element of one of the lists, by passing `([x[0], x[2]] for x in listA)` (again, an iterator) instead of `listA` (same for the other lists). Then, you also need to change `x[2] for x in vals` in `calculate` to `x[1] for x in vals`

Comment: nevermind I think I understand how to work with the iterators as they are passed through.  thanks again @hit